# What is the best way to store and manage tahini?

Tags: storage-method, emulsion

I don't use my tahini too often, and sometimes when I open a can that's been sitting on the shelf, the oil has separated from the pastey part so much, that the pastey part is like a rock.

Is there a way to store tahini longterm without this separating happening?
Once it happens is there a way to recover it?  A food processor didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oil will always separate from the rest of the product. (home made or natural/bio peanut butter will behave the same way)

When that happens, just spend some time and elbow grease to mix it back together again.

if the tahini was stored in the fridge, it might take longer because everything will be harder.

Just leave it on the counter for a while until it gets to room temperature before mixing it back together.

(after googling) People suggest to keep the jar upside down and when you want to use it, just put it back straight and let it stand for a while, it will mix itself (a little bit) together again.

Comment: Storing in the fridge indeed pretty much prevents this. I've gone through large jars over many months stored in the fridge without really re-stirring, and there's a little bit of a harder layer at the very bottom at the end, but not enough to worry about.

Comment: My jar split even in the fridge; maybe there is a difference between brands.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Mine was split at room temperature, so I'm pretty sure it helped still, but I guess it's not the end all be all solution.

Comment: It usually works for peanut butter pretty well, to mix it and put it in the fridge.  I guess tahini has more of a tendency to separate though refridgerating it might make it happen slower.

Answer (score 2):

I stored in the cabinet and when I went to use it it was fully separated. I used a fork to break up the hard bottom that had settled and then I used an immersion blender and that worked great!  The immersion blender made it very smooth and completely incorporated the liquid and solid into a smooth creamy tahini paste.

Answer (score 0):

I store tahini upside down in fridge door area since I live in the desert and the pantry still gets warm even with air conditioning on.